# Java XML to HTML with XSLT xml-stylesheet location

Tags: java, xslt

I'm using Java to load an XSLT file from the resources directory and transform an XML into HTML. The XML stylesheet is defined in the XSLT as follows:

```
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>
```

I get the following error when I try and load the XSLT:

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("C:\\dev\\myproject\\src\\main\\resources\\feefo\\feedback.xsl"));
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
```

> ERROR:  'C:\dev\myproject\style.css (The system cannot find the file
>   specified)'

How do I fix this problem? I will be putting the  XSLT and style.css file into the resources directory.

Complete XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>
 <html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:variable name="feefostarsimageroot" select="'http://cdn.feefo.com/feefo/resources/images/rating'" />
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>FeeFo Feedback</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
 <body>
     <div id="page" itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness" itemscope="itemscope">
     <!-- tr class=row -->
           <div class="comments">

               <xsl:for-each select="FEEDBACKLIST/SUMMARY">
                   <h1><span itemprop="name">
                       <xsl:choose>
                           <xsl:when test="COUNT > 1">
                               <xsl:value-of select="concat(TITLE,' reviews')"/>
                           </xsl:when>
                           <xsl:otherwise>
                               <xsl:value-of select="concat(TITLE,' review')"/>
                           </xsl:otherwise>
                       </xsl:choose>
                   </span></h1>

               <span>
                   <a>
                       <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="concat('http://www.feefo.com/feefo/viewvendor.jsp?logon=',VENDORLOGON)"/></xsl:attribute>
                       <img itemprop="image">
                           <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="SUPPLIERLOGO"/></xsl:attribute>
                           <xsl:attribute name="alt">Feefologo</xsl:attribute>
                       </img>
                   </a>

                   <p class="supplier">
                       <div itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" itemscope="itemscope" itemprop="aggregateRating">
                           <span itemprop="ratingValue"><xsl:attribute name="content"><xsl:value-of select="AVERAGE"/>%</xsl:attribute></span>
                           <span itemprop="bestRating"><xsl:attribute name="content"><xsl:value-of select="BEST"/></xsl:attribute></span>
                           <span itemprop="worstRating"><xsl:attribute name="content"><xsl:value-of select="WORST"/></xsl:attribute></span>
                           Feedback for <xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/> has been compiled from <strong><span itemprop="reviewCount"><xsl:value-of select="TOTALSERVICECOUNT"/></span></strong> customer reviews</div>
                   </p>

               </span>
               </xsl:for-each>
               <table class="comm-table">
                   <tr>
                       <th width="100">Date</th>
                       <th width="200">Product</th>

                       <th width="90">Score</th>
                       <th>Customer Comment</th>
                   </tr>
                   <xsl:for-each select="FEEDBACKLIST/FEEDBACK">

                       <tr itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" itemscope="itemscope" itemprop="review">
                       <td><!-- time tag used here in HTML5 only might cause issues with legacy browsers -->
                           <a target="new"><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="READMOREURL" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></xsl:attribute>
                           <time itemprop="datePublished"><xsl:attribute name="datetime"><xsl:value-of select="HREVIEWDATE" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="DATE" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></time>
                           </a>
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           <h3 class="item">
                               <xsl:choose>
                                   <xsl:when test="LINK">
                                       <a>
                                           <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="LINK" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></xsl:attribute>
                                           <span><xsl:value-of select="DESCRIPTION" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></span>
                                       </a>
                                   </xsl:when>
                                   <xsl:otherwise>
                                       <span><xsl:value-of select="DESCRIPTION" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></span>
                                   </xsl:otherwise>
                               </xsl:choose>
                               <span itemprop="name"><xsl:attribute name="content"><xsl:value-of select="/FEEDBACKLIST/SUMMARY/TITLE" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></xsl:attribute></span>
                           </h3>

                           <xsl:if test="ADDITIONALITEMS">
                               <span class="alsobought"><ul>
                                   <li>Customer also bought: .... :</li>
                                   <xsl:for-each select="ADDITIONALITEMS/ITEM">
                                       <li><xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" /></li>
                                   </xsl:for-each>
                               </ul></span>
                            </xsl:if>
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           <div class="comm-rating">
                           <!-- I added this, need to adapt with the below -->
                           <xsl:if test="SERVICERATING">
                               <xsl:if test="PRODUCTRATING">
                                   <em>Service:</em>
                                   </xsl:if>
                                   <xsl:variable name="serviceratingnumber">
                                       <xsl:choose>
                                           <xsl:when test="SERVICERATING = '++'">5</xsl:when>
                                           <xsl:when test="SERVICERATING = '+'">4</xsl:when>
                                           <xsl:when test="SERVICERATING = '-'">2</xsl:when>
                                           <xsl:when test="SERVICERATING = '--'">1</xsl:when>
                                           <xsl:when test="SERVICERATING = 'W'">W</xsl:when>
                                           <xsl:otherwise>norating</xsl:otherwise>
                                       </xsl:choose>
                                   </xsl:variable>
                                   <!-- this uses feefo images -->
                                   <img>
                                       <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="concat($feefostarsimageroot,$serviceratingnumber,'.png')"/></xsl:attribute>
                                       <xsl:attribute name="alt"><xsl:value-of select="SERVICERATING"/></xsl:attribute>
                                   </img>
                                   <!-- the old method of displaying images using local assets has been removed -->
                                   <xsl:if test="not(SERVICELATEST)">
                                    <xsl:if test="$serviceratingnumber != '' and $serviceratingnumber != 'W' and $serviceratingnumber != 'norating'">
                                       <div itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating" itemscope="itemscope" itemprop="reviewRating">
                                           <meta content="1" itemprop="worstRating"/>
                                           <span itemprop="ratingValue"><xsl:attribute name="content"><xsl:value-of select="$serviceratingnumber"/></xsl:attribute></span>
                                           <span content="5" itemprop="bestRating"></span>
                                       </div>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                   </xsl:if>
                           </xsl:if>
                          <!-- I now need to sort out product, I've done service -->
                           <xsl:if test="string(PRODUCTRATING)">
                               <xsl:if test="SERVICERATING">
                                   <em>Product:</em>
                               </xsl:if>
                               <xsl:variable name="productratingnumber">
                                   <xsl:choose>
                                       <xsl:when test="PRODUCTRATING = '++'">5</xsl:when>
                                       <xsl:when test="PRODUCTRATING = '+'">4</xsl:when>
                                       <xsl:when test="PRODUCTRATING = '-'">2</xsl:when>
                                       <xsl:when test="PRODUCTRATING = '--'">1</xsl:when>
                                       <xsl:when test="PRODUCTRATING = 'W'">W</xsl:when>
                                       <xsl:otherwise>norating</xsl:otherwise>
                                   </xsl:choose>
                               </xsl:variable>

                               <img>
                                   <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="concat($feefostarsimageroot,$productratingnumber,'.png')"/></xsl:attribute>
                                   <xsl:attribute name="alt"><xsl:value-of select="PRODUCTRATING"/></xsl:attribute>
                               </img>
                               <xsl:if test="HREVIEWRATING != ''">
                                   <xsl:if test="not(PRODUCTLATEST)">
                                       <xsl:if test="not(SERVICERATING)"> <!-- do the rating against the product in product only mode -->
                                           <div itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating" itemscope="itemscope" itemprop="reviewRating">
                                               <meta content="1" itemprop="worstRating"/>
                                               <span itemprop="ratingValue"><xsl:attribute name="content"><xsl:value-of select="HREVIEWRATING"/></xsl:attribute></span>
                                               <span content="5" itemprop="bestRating"></span>
                                           </div>
                                       </xsl:if>
                                   </xsl:if>
                               </xsl:if>

                            </xsl:if>
                               <xsl:if test="SERVICELATEST">
                                   <xsl:variable name="servicelatestnumber">
                                       <xsl:choose>
                                           <xsl:when test="SERVICELATEST = '++'">5</xsl:when>
                                           <xsl:when test="SERVICELATEST = '+'">4</xsl:when>
                                           <xsl:when test="SERVICELATEST = '-'">2</xsl:when>
                                           <xsl:when test="SERVICELATEST = '--'">1</xsl:when>
                                           <xsl:otherwise>norating</xsl:otherwise>
                                       </xsl:choose>
                                   </xsl:variable>
                                   <em>Latest:</em>
                                   <xsl:if test="PRODUCTRATING">
                                           <em>Service</em>
                                   </xsl:if>
                                   <img>
                                       <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="concat($feefostarsimageroot,$servicelatestnumber,'.png')"/></xsl:attribute>
                                       <xsl:attribute name="alt"><xsl:value-of select="SERVICELATEST"/></xsl:attribute>
                                   </img>
                                   <xsl:if test="$servicelatestnumber != '' and $servicelatestnumber != 'W' and $servicelatestnumber != 'norating'">
                                       <div itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating" itemscope="itemscope" itemprop="reviewRating">
                                           <meta content="1" itemprop="worstRating"/>
                                           <span itemprop="ratingValue"><xsl:attribute name="content"><xsl:value-of select="$servicelatestnumber"/></xsl:attribute></span>
                                           <span content="5" itemprop="bestRating"></span>
                                       </div>
                                   </xsl:if>
                               </xsl:if>
                               <xsl:if test="PRODUCTLATEST and PRODUCTLATEST != '0'">
                                   <xsl:variable name="productlatestnumber">
                                       <xsl:choose>
                                           <xsl:when test="PRODUCTLATEST = '++'">5</xsl:when>
                                           <xsl:when test="PRODUCTLATEST = '+'">4</xsl:when>
                                           <xsl:when test="PRODUCTLATEST = '-'">2</xsl:when>
                                           <xsl:when test="PRODUCTLATEST = '--'">1</xsl:when>
                                           <xsl:otherwise>norating</xsl:otherwise>
                                       </xsl:choose>
                                   </xsl:variable>

                                   <xsl:if test="not(SERVICELATEST)">
                                       <em>Latest:</em>
                                   </xsl:if>
                                   <xsl:if test="SERVICERATING">
                                       <em>Product:</em>
                                   </xsl:if>
                                   <img>
                                       <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="concat($feefostarsimageroot,$productlatestnumber,'.png')"/></xsl:attribute>
                                       <xsl:attribute name="alt"><xsl:value-of select="PRODUCTLATEST"/></xsl:attribute>
                                   </img>
                                   <xsl:if test="not(SERVICERATING)"> <!-- do the rating against the product in product only mode -->
                                       <div itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating" itemscope="itemscope" itemprop="reviewRating">
                                           <meta content="1" itemprop="worstRating"/>
                                           <span itemprop="ratingValue"><xsl:attribute name="content"><xsl:value-of select="$productlatestnumber"/></xsl:attribute></span>
                                           <span content="5" itemprop="bestRating"></span>
                                       </div>
                                   </xsl:if>
                               </xsl:if>
                           </div>
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           <p itemprop="description">
                              <xsl:value-of select="CUSTOMERCOMMENT" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                           </p>
                           <xsl:for-each select="FURTHERCOMMENTSTHREAD/POST">
                               <xsl:if test="CUSTOMERCOMMENT">
                                   <br />
                                   <div class="customercomment">
                                   <p>On <xsl:value-of select="DATE" /> the customer
                                       <xsl:if test="SERVICERATING or PRODUCTRATING"> changed their rating and </xsl:if>
                                       added:<br/> <xsl:value-of select="CUSTOMERCOMMENT" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></p>
                                   <a target="new"><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="../../READMOREURL" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></xsl:attribute>See this exchange on Feefo </a>
                                   </div>
                               </xsl:if>
                               <xsl:if test="VENDORCOMMENT">
                                   <br />
                                   <div class="vendorcomment">
                                   <p>On <xsl:value-of select="DATE" /> the supplier responded:<br />
                                        <xsl:value-of select="VENDORCOMMENT" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                                   </p>
                                   </div>
                               </xsl:if>
                           </xsl:for-each>

                       </td>
                       </tr>
                   </xsl:for-each>
               </table>
           </div>
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're confusing CSS with XSLT. They are both called "stylesheets" but are completely different animals.

Comment: @JimGarrison That xml-stylesheet is defined at the top of my xsl file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing CSS with XSLT. They are both called "stylesheets" but are completely different animals.

The `<?xml-stylesheet ...>` is an XML Processing Instruction that provides metadata used by the XML processor, in this case providing an href to the XSL stylesheet that can be used to transform the XML.  You are already providing that when you invoke the XSL Transformer, so the `<?xml-stylesheet ...>` PI is unnecessary.

A CSS stylesheet is something you would refer to in the header of the output HTML, and is completely unrelated to the `<?xml-stylesheet ...>` PI.  If the location is variable you may need to provide that as a parameter to the transformation so it can be substituted at the correct location in the generated HTML.

If the `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>` is provided to you then whoever created the XML document does not understand the purpose of this Processing Instruction.  It should not be there.

EDIT after seeing the OP's question edit:

That's even worse.  `<?xml-stylesheet...?>` does not belong in an XSL document.  Just remove it and move on.  It does not belong there at all.

As to the CSS, you already have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

at the proper location in the XSL